# Copy to Clipboard using JavaScript: Multiple Input Values, but one Function?

Tags: javascript, html, copy, clipboard

I'm trying to create a small (local) page that allows me to copy frequently used texts to the clipboard by clicking on a button.

My code (see below) works so far.

Now my question:

Is there a way to adapt the Javascript code so that I don't have to create my own/new Javascript function for every new  field (there are very, very many) and never have to adjust the Javascript-Code again?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Copy!</title>
        <script>
            function c1() {
                var c = document.getElementById("c1");
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(c.value);
            }
            function c2() {
                var c = document.getElementById("c2");
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(c.value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>
            I want to be copied!<br />
            <input type="text" value="First value to be copied" id="c1"> <button onclick="c1()">Copy the first value!</button>
        </span>
        <br /><br />
        <span>
            But I also want to be copied<br />
            <input type="text" value="And the second value" id="c2"> <button onclick="c2()">And now the second!</button>
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Solution**. I believe there will be a better way of doing this. But This code is working now.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Copy To Clipboard</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Text 1 -->
    <form class="copyText">
      <input type="text" />
      <button>Copy Text</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Text 2 -->
    <form class="copyText">
      <input type="text" />
      <button>Copy Text</button>
    </form>

    <!-- JavaScript -->
    <script>
      const copyText = document.getElementsByClassName("copyText");

      for(let i = 0; i < copyText.length; i++) {
        copyText[i].addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

          // Prevent Default (It's required)
          e.preventDefault()

          // In my case 0 element is input
          navigator.clipboard.writeText(e.target.children[0].value)
        })
      }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, RKS!

But with your solution, the contents of all VALUEs are copied with a single button. But I need a button for each input field, so i can copy all different values from the inputs individually and not at the same time.

Comment: In that case, pass the event to the click callback, then don't iterate over all items with the class. Use the event's target instead: `totalText = e.target.value;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, mykaf. Unfortunately, since I'm completely new to JS, I can't do anything with it and can't get it to work.

My only goal is to use very clean JS code.

Comment: What did you try from that example that doesn't work? How doesn't it work? Are there any error messages?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what i have to change to make it work the way I need it. So there is a separate button for each INPUT field, which only copies the value of the INPUT field next to the button (and not all values from all INPUT fields).

Comment: I modified the code. With `form` element and a `button` for each input text.

Answer (score -1):

Start by adding an event listener to the "copyable" zone. On click, check that the click's target is a button OR that it has a button as its parent (to make sure we include the text within the button).  If we clicked within the button, get its previous element sibling, the input and copy its value to the clipboard.

```js
document.querySelector("div#copyable").addEventListener(
    "click",
  function(e) {
    const theButton = e.target.closest("button");
    if (theButton) {
        const theText = theButton.previousElementSibling.value;
      navigator.clipboard.writeText(theText);
      console.log("now try pasting somewhere")
    }
    
  }
 )
```

```html
<div id="copyable">


<span>
            I want to be copied!<br />
            <input type="text" value="First value to be copied" id="c1"> <button type="button" class="copyButton">Copy the first value!</button>
        </span>
        <br /><br />
        <span>
            But I also want to be copied<br />
            <input type="text" value="And the second value" id="c2"> <button type="button" class="copyButton">And now the second!</button>
        </span>
</div>
```